# Bootstrap: Collapse others when one is expanded

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

Hello guys (Sorry for english i ll do my best)
i have a serious problem with my dropdown menus. I want to hide others when one is open like accordion. I just started bootstrap and it's the first time i see the data-toggle, i think it's with it i need to work.

help me please:

this is the nav section:

```js
      $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
            });

        });
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdowns-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
    /* don't forget to add all the previously mentioned styles here too */
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #E6A343;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    color: white
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #A66D00;
    background: white;
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #BF7A30;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #FFB03D;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style-sidebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style-header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style-content.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <title>Gestion-Filinea</title>
</head>

<body>










    <header>
        <div class="page-header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#"><img src="images/logo3.png" width="200" height="60" alt=""></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accueil<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Organisme</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu-déroulant</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu3</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Personne</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu-déroulant</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu3</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Menu</h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                   <a href="#OrgSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Organismes</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="OrgSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Organismes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter Organisme</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher Organisme</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#CoachSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Coachs</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="CoachSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Coachs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter coach</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher coach</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#PersonneSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Personnes</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="PersonneSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Personnes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter personne</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher personne</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#MandantSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Mandants</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="MandantSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Mandants</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter Mandant</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher Mandant</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#MêtierSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Mêtiers</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="MêtierSubmenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Mêtiers</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter Mêtier</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher Mêtier</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Déconnexion</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead class="thead-light">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                                        <th scope="col">First</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                                        <td>Mark</td>
                                        <td>Otto</td>
                                        <td>@mdo</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                                        <td>Jacob</td>
                                        <td>Thornton</td>
                                        <td>@fat</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                                        <td>Larry</td>
                                        <td>the Bird</td>
                                        <td>@twitter</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Tell me if you need something else.

Comment: If you use BootStrap, there is a lot of things already done that you could remove from what you posted.  Check these examples, they work and show you how to use the objects.  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/  There are 4 pages related to only nabvars.

Comment: But what's the best option Here ? Remove what i have done from Bootstrap or use the toggle from Bootstrap ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget about whether the code your wrote is general or not. I focus on work that you want.
Basically, this kind of a implement is an easy thing.
You just get each click event, and remove all the active classes first, then put the active class to only clicked element. However, I checked [the accordion of Bootstrap Document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example), and I found it 'data-parent', and it seems 'data-parent' can be apply your case.

I added 'data-parent="#sidebar"' each ul element.

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#sidebar {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#sidebar.active {
    margin-left: -250px;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdowns-toggle::after {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar {
    /* don't forget to add all the previously mentioned styles here too */
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #E6A343;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    color: white
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #A66D00;
    background: white;
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #BF7A30;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #FFB03D;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style-sidebar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style-header.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style-content.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->

    <title>Gestion-Filinea</title>
</head>

<body>










    <header>
        <div class="page-header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#"><img src="images/logo3.png" width="200" height="60" alt=""></a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Accueil<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Organisme</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu-déroulant</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu3</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Personne</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu-déroulant</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu1</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu2</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Menu3</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Menu</h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                   <a href="#OrgSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Organismes</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="OrgSubmenu" data-parent="#sidebar">
                        <li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Organismes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter Organisme</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher Organisme</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#CoachSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Coachs</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="CoachSubmenu" data-parent="#sidebar">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Coachs</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter coach</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher coach</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#PersonneSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Personnes</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="PersonneSubmenu" data-parent="#sidebar">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Personnes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter personne</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher personne</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#MandantSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Mandants</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="MandantSubmenu" data-parent="#sidebar">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Mandants</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter Mandant</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher Mandant</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#MêtierSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Mêtiers</a>
                        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="MêtierSubmenu" data-parent="#sidebar">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Lister Mêtiers</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Ajouter Mêtier</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Chercher Mêtier</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Déconnexion</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="page-content">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead class="thead-light">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                                        <th scope="col">First</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Last</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                                        <td>Mark</td>
                                        <td>Otto</td>
                                        <td>@mdo</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">2</th>
                                        <td>Jacob</td>
                                        <td>Thornton</td>
                                        <td>@fat</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="row">3</th>
                                        <td>Larry</td>
                                        <td>the Bird</td>
                                        <td>@twitter</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```